# What is the keyboard shortcut to directly focus the first Google search result, in Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

Currently hitting Tab goes to top-bar / side-bar options and then the first search result. Is there any such keyboard shortcut that will directly focus on search results?

Comment: Are you talking about Google Search?

Comment: @AlEverett Yes. Updated the title.

Comment: When I hit tab in Chrome or Firefox I get to the first search result. Subsequent hits on tab bring me to the next result.

Comment: For me too in FF pressing Tab causes a small ► to show up to the left of the 1st search result, and then I can use the up/down arrow keys to move through the results list.

Comment: Tested on a clean profile of the latest stable release on Firefox - tab does focus to the first search result. It seems that an extension/preference is disrupting this behaviour. Try clearing all of your data (Ctrl+Shift+Del) and then try again.

Comment: FYI, to get back to the google search box (not omnibar) press ESC after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser update fixed it. Al Everett is correct. "When I hit tab in Chrome or Firefox I get to the first search result. Subsequent hits on tab bring me to the next result."

Answer (score 1):

There is an add-on for Firefox that allows to navigate Google search results using keyboard arrows (or tab):

> Google™ Search Result Shortcuts by Jacob
>
> Adds keyboard shortcuts back to Google search results

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-search-result-shortcuts/

Another useful feature is that if you navigate through results and then resume with typing (characters) it re-focus on the search box.

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut <kbd>F7</kbd> could be handy in this case. It will enable you to browse the page using keyboard

Comment: Sorry, doesn't seem to do anything.